# What should be done with an Access database that is getting too large?

Tags: ms-access-2007

It may be vague and hopefully the right site to ask, but I am not really privvy to Access and programming. 
I have a manager that created an Access database and some front end stuff for transportation related tracking and employee data info. It has grown to a 2 gig filesize, and now multiple users accessing. From what I've read this should be imported and used from a SQL server of some sort. Is there a best practice for what type of server software to use, or just moving out of the Acccess limitations? Again sorry for the naivety...

Comment: Has the data file been compacted? It could be that it's just been abused and has a lot of discardable data pages in it. It could also have a bunch of temporary data, or old tables that are no longer in use. Of course, if after a cleanup/compact, it remains in the 1GB range, I'd still vote for upsizing.

Comment: I agree, my understanding tells me Access kinda blows for production environments, and would be better off with SQL server anyway. Would I be right in assuming it would increase performance as well, when it comes to multiple users performing queries?

Comment: Access/Jet/ACE does not "blow" for production environments if it's an appropriate data store for the specific application and its operating environment. In this case, there are questions as to whether its capacity has really been exceeded or if the file is just in really bad condition because of a complete lack of any maintenance (a SQL Server will cause big problems if you never do any maintenance on it, too).

Comment: Compacting a back-end data file will improve performance because it rewrites data pages in continguous order (clustered on the PK of each table), and gets rid of all the slack space. It's not just table data pages that get rewritten but index data pages, and that's pretty important (likely moreso for non-PK indexes than for the PK itself).

Comment: @David Thanks a bunch, I'll probe him for more information about his maintenance to his files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can and should migrate the data to SQL Server.

Here is how: http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/migration-access.aspx

Comment: Lots of other databases are good candidates for upsizing, such as MySQL or PostgreSQL. If the questioner has experience with a different server database, it can likely be used just as successfully with an Access front end as SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

Or if practical, you could simply export and delete the old data, especially if you're not using it anymore. If you have a couple years worth of data, you probably can delete the early years of activity and recover some space.

Comment: I vote against ever archiving anything. If your data needs outgrow Jet/ACE's capabilities, then upsize.